# Capistrano: use Bundle Gems from standard Gem-Home

Tags: ruby, capistrano, bundler

When deploying with Capistrano I want to use installed gems instead of installing them into `vendor`.

Capistrano seems to ignore `.gemrc` & `.bashrc`, so I tried this in `deploy.rb`:

```
require 'bundler/capistrano'

set :default_environment, {
  'GEM_HOME'     => '/some_path/.gem',
  'GEM_PATH'     => '/some_path/.gem',
  'BUNDLE_PATH'  => '/some_path/.gem'
}
```

My gems are located in `/some_path/.gem/gems`, bin: `/some_path/.gem/bin`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can tell bundler where gems should go (or are I believe) and pass the --local to install from the local gem caches as opposed to fetching from http://rubygems.org

```
bundle install --local --path='/some_path/.gem
```

Answer (score 3):

If you are doing

```
require 'bundler/capistrano'
```

Put this in deploy.rb to set bundle install's --path arg:

```
set :bundle_dir, "/path/to/gems"
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's what I have in my `config/deploy.rb` to tell bundler to install gems into "system" gems:

```
require "bundler/capistrano"
set :bundle_dir,     ""         # install into "system" gems
set :bundle_flags,   "--quiet"  # no verbose output
set :bundle_without, []         # bundle all gems (even dev & test)
```

http://paulgoscicki.com/archives/2011/10/tell-bundler-to-install-gems-globally-when-using-capistrano/

Answer (score 1):

It is the manifestation of the YAML engine switch from Syck to Psych and all of the incompatibilities it has brought. The problem is that now you have to reinstall all of your gems, because all installed gems have wrong gemspec specification.