# Libv8 & therubyracer - Full install on every new site deployment?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capistrano, therubyracer, libv8

I have a Ubuntu 12.04 server and several rails 3.2.14 sites on it. Every time I do a new site deployment (via capistrano) the first install takes 20 - 30 minutes because it does a full install of libv8, even though I have already installed the libv8 gem on the machine (and see it when I do a `gem list`).

I've tried the [binary version](https://github.com/cowboyd/libv8) and tried changing versions of therubyracer.

Here's therubyracer part of my Gemfile

```
group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.2.6'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.2.2'
      gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'
  gem 'therubyracer', '~> 0.12.0'
end
```

I've turned on verbose output in Capistrano and here's where it hangs up for ~20 minutes

`** [out :: 198.58.99.7] Installing libv8 (3.16.14.3)`

Any suggestions? Really tired of new sites taking this long to deploy.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "new site deployment". As far as I understand it, Capistrano uses the `--deployment` bundler flag when installing gems, and this tells it, among other things, to instal the gems to `your_app/shared/bundle/`, which means it's different for every new deployment.

Comment: ok, is there a way that you know of to use a machine version of the gem (instead of compiling libv8 for each new Rails site)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I said in my comment, `bundle` with the `--deployment` flag (as Capistrano does) installs gems into a `your_app/shared/bundle`. One of the reasons for this isolation and location is because the user you're deploying with may not have access to install gems to a system location, and more reasons described [here](http://bundler.io/v1.5/deploying.html) (under the Deploying Your Application heading).

I believe there are ways to force bundler to use the system gems but I don't have any first hand experience of it; see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4808419/capistrano-use-bundle-gems-from-standard-gem-home).

Answer (score 0):

There's probably a conflict in dependencies in your `Gemfile`.

Remove the version constraint for `therubyracer` in your `Gemfile` and bundling should be much faster.

```
gem 'therubyracer'
```

Comment: Max, thanks for reply, previously I didn't have version in there (actually for a site yesterday) and unfortunately still had the same issue. Any other suggestions?

Comment: Try this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8126465/bundle-install-update-libv8-therubyracer-installation-fails-with-native-ex